# How to avoid the error message when using thymeleaf templates in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I'm using spring boot and thymeleaf in Intellij Idea and try to get the parameters of the URL in the template, I use the following code:

```
<!--/*@thymesVar id="param" type="java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>"*/-->
<a th:href="@{/dashboard(version=${param.version})}">Dashboard</a>
```

It works correctly, but I want to clear the error message, Is there any good way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error. If you run your application, It is supposed to work (If there is no other errors), as you mentioned that It's working correctly. The `JetBrains`/ `IntelliJ` is not able to locate your model variables with `Thymeleaf` framework. So that's why I does show the red underline. For more details check the link [how to resolve JetBrains model variables](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738).

Hopefully in next version of `IntelliJ IDEA`, this issue would get resolved.

Let us know If It was helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm using the `@thymesVar` tag to locate my model variables. In most cases, it works well, but when I use java.util.Map in `@thymesVar` tag, it does not recognize correctly.

Comment: It’s a workaround. This issue exists at the IDE level. So it won’t satisfy the developers feeling unless it gets fixed by JetBrains team.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
${param['version']}
```

Goodluck..